# Drawing dovetail pattern on a table

Tags: tables, draw

I have a table with empty cells:

[image: empty table]

I want to create lines (preferably in another color) on the table that will signify that cells are being passed in a "dovetail" pattern. Something like:

[image: table with dovetail patern]

The code for the table creation:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ c|c|c|c|c|c }
\diagbox{$r$}{$d$}    & $2^0$ & $2^1$ & $2^2$ & $2^3$ & $\cdots$ \\ \hline 
 $2^{0}$  &       &       &       &       & \\ \hline
 $2^{-1}$  &       &       &       &       & \\ \hline
 $2^{-2}$  &       &       &       &       & \\ \hline
 $2^{-3}$  &       &       &       &       & \\ \hline
 \vdots &       &       &       &       & \\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following might give you an idea how to start:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usepackage{diagbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ c|c|c|c|c|c }
\diagbox{$r$}{$d$}    & $2^0$ & $2^1$ & $2^2$ & $2^3$ & $\cdots$ \\ \hline 
 $2^{0}$  &  \tikzmark{a}    &  \tikzmark{b}    &   \tikzmark{f}    &       & \\ \hline
 $2^{-1}$  &   \tikzmark{c}    &   \tikzmark{e}    &       &       & \\ \hline
 $2^{-2}$  &  \tikzmark{d}     &       &       &       & \\ \hline
 $2^{-3}$  &       &       &       &       & \\ \hline
 \vdots &       &       &       &       & \\
\end{tabular}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\draw[red](pic cs:a)--(pic cs:b)--(pic cs:c)--(pic cs:d)--(pic cs:e) --(pic cs:f);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

If you prefer rounded corners, you can add something like `rounded corners=3pt` to the options of the draw command and recieve the following:

[image]

With `\draw[red] plot[smooth] coordinates {(pic cs:a) (pic cs:b) (pic cs:c) (pic cs:d) (pic cs:e) (pic cs:f)};`  as recommended by Schrödinger's cat [in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/523937/drawing-dovetail-pattern-on-a-table/523939#comment1325468_523939) you get the following output:

[image]

Comment: +1. Maybe also add `\draw[red] plot[smooth] coordinates {(pic cs:a) (pic cs:b) (pic cs:c) (pic cs:d)
(pic cs:e) (pic cs:f)};` to the options.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat: Thanks for pointing this out. Until now I wasn't aware of the `smooth` option.